# using multiple mapbox wmts baselayers with dififerent labels in QGIS composer

Tags: print-composer, qgis-2.18, mapbox-studio

I have created two basemap layers in mapbox.

1. https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/akrystos/cjr1epzf905a32sqhkwvjl5i7.html?fresh=true&title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYWtyeXN0b3MiLCJhIjoiY2o0YWI5Ynh0MTJleTMzbGNiMmNycXJtMyJ9.usNtifL5jfkUdC0NgNvChQ#5.0/0.400000/37.850000/0
2. https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/akrystos/cjr1f15ar91b72rpcgrgtzhb9.html?fresh=true&title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYWtyeXN0b3MiLCJhIjoiY2o0YWI5Ynh0MTJleTMzbGNiMmNycXJtMyJ9.usNtifL5jfkUdC0NgNvChQ#5.0/0.400000/37.850000/0

I am using basemap 1 in a main map in group 1 with my data layer. 
I am using basemap 2 in an inset map in group 2.

The two maps appear in the composer correctly and are refreshed/locked. But, once I export the map to pdf, the labels in both maps revert to whatever is in the dataframe view of arcgis.

Any thoughts?

As a workaround, I exported the inset as an image and added it to the composer as a static image.

QGIS version 2.18.27
windows 10 pro

Amy

Please see the images of the data view, composer, and exported pdf below.

*The composer and data view of the two maps*
[image: The composer and data view of the two maps]

---

*The composer and exported PDF of the two maps*
[image: The composer and exported PDF of the two maps]

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the *error with the PDF*?

Comment: Please see the images of the data view, composer, and exported pdf below. 
[![The composer and data view of the two maps][1]][1]


[![The composer and exported PDF of the two maps][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw2gq.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM0Tz.png

Comment: From the images, it looks like the **Data View** & **Print Composer** match.  And **Print Composer** & **PDF** match.  Likely the problem is in the source Mapbox style.